# apply a function by rows but without apply function in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I am trying to apply a function that takes a matrix and divides each element by the sum of its row.  Specifically I have the matrix

```
mat <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2)
```

And I apply a function `calculateContributions` to each row like this:

```
apply(mat, 1, calculateContributions)
```

The `calculateContributions` function is defined:

```
calculateContributions <- function(X){
  return(X/sum(X))
}
```

That gives me the result I need, but since the apply function is very slow  and I need to compute this many times, this solution is not good. I think maybe the function `with` could help but I do not know how to use it to apply a function by rows.

Comment: How about just `mat/rowSums(mat)`?

Comment: I see that it works, but I don't understand how to compute the response, I mean, how I know that the first element of the first row should be divided by the first element in rowSums(mat) and so on. Sorry but I am new in r

Comment: Each row divided by it's row sum. e.g: for the first row its 1/25, 3/25, 5/25, etc. For the second row its 2/30, 4/30, 6/30, etc. This is just the way how vectorized language works- a whole vector is being applied each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DavidArenburg suggests,

```
mat/rowSums(mat)
```

seems like the easiest way to do this. Testing with `1e5` elements;

```
mat <- matrix(sample(1:100,1e5,replace=TRUE), ncol = 5) 
dim(mat)
[1] 20000     5

library(microbenchmark)    
microbenchmark(a <- mat/rowSums(mat), unit="ms")
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean    median      uq      max neval
# *    0.767314 0.7937865 0.8235583 0.8070225 0.81532 2.461567   100

calculateContributions <- function(X){
  return(X/sum(X))
}

microbenchmark(b <- apply(mat, 1, calculateContributions), unit="ms")
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# *    84.44795 86.19673 89.37455 87.41942 89.72254 164.3082   100
```

so 100x faster to just do the matrix division.

Worse still, the result of the `apply` call is the transposed matrix (credit: @DavidArenburg) so you still need to convert back. When you do, you get the exact same result as the matrix division.

```
identical(a, t(b))
[1] TRUE
```

Sidenote: (I'm still new here) why do people add valid answers as comments (and why do I get downvoted for making those answers with attribution and extra detail?).

Comment: +1 and I appreciate you adding the benchmark.  There are answers on Meta to your question of why sometimes people post answers as comments, e.g., http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments.  Re: the downvoting, maybe people think you are trying to benefit from someone else's work - but especially if you're expanding on the comment, that's petty.  StackOverflow users benefit as a whole from having an answer posted.

Comment: Unless you're adding something substantial towards the answer, I think asking the original commenter to post it as an answer is the chivalrous thing to do (particularly if you're the OP). Alternately, turn it into a community wiki answer, especially if multiple people have posted pieces in the comments.

Comment: I wasn't aware this will cause so much drama. The reason I haven't posted an answer is because it is an obvious dupe and I was too lazy to Google it before going to bed.

Comment: And as a side note, your statement regarding `apply` is fundamentally wrong. `apply` *always* returns a matrix by definition. Just check `class(b)`. The return matrix is just transposed so you could simply do `t(b)` to transpose back.

Comment: My bad, hastily added after the fact as an addendum when I noticed it wasn't identical to `a`. Will update.